# Looking for Coral M.2 Accelerator + RHEL/Centos 8 Drivers on x86_64

Tags: driver, centos8, google-coral

I'm a little lost (and admit that I'm pretty green to all this). I am looking for the drivers for the M.2 drivers for RHEL/CentOS 8 on x86_64 architecture. Previously I was successful installing the drivers under Ubuntu following the Getting Started guide on the Coral website (https://coral.ai/docs/m2/get-started). But I need to run CentOS 8 for other reasons. So I know that the board works. I know it can be supported in Linux, but don't know how to convert the instructions for CentOS.

My M.2 board is connected to my server using a M.2 to PCIe adapter.

Thanks in advance!

ben

Answer (score 0):

I also believe that you should be able to get this working.
Couple things that you'll need:

- libedgetpu.so - You can download the latest runtime from here: https://github.com/google-coral/edgetpu/tree/master/libedgetpu/direct/k8
- apex/gasket modules - This is a required kernel module for talking to the pcie module. This is going to be very tricky, first you'll need to make sure that you don't already have apex/gasket module already installed. If you do, blacklist it and load our modules. Now our modules cannot be installed with `apt-get` since you are in centos, so your only option is to download the code from source and compile it on your own: https://coral.googlesource.com/linux-imx/+/refs/heads/release-day/drivers/staging/gasket

Cheers

Comment: Thanks Nam. More tricky than I want it to be! :-(
I guess, I'm not trying to reinvent the wheel. If Coral is easiest/works on Debian, why change it, right? Maybe I'll run a Debian/Ubuntu VM inside CentOS/RHEL instead!